# How to add a test device to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter application with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) integration
but I want to add my physical device or emulator as a test device
to test the notifications on this device only without releasing to all production devices
.. how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

follow this steps :

1- add a debug print of the FCM token to your apps start by adding this line :

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((value) => print(value));
```

2- run your app in debug mode and copy the token , it will look like this :

```
I/flutter ( 6513): Really_lage_token
```

3- login to your Firebase console and add a new notification :

[image]

4- click on send test message and add your token from step 2

[image]

5- click test and repeat for each test notification .